# Not able to set default jdk ubuntu using update-java-alternatives

Tags: java, android, linux, oracle, ubuntu

I upgraded my Android Studio to latest 2.2 version. When I start I get the following error:

`Android Studio Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_65-b17: Java 1.8 or later is required.`

On finding out solution I had to upgrade to java 1.8, below is the command confirming its installation

`ubuntu@ubuntu-Vostro-1450:/usr/lib$ sudo  update-java-alternatives --list
java-7-oracle 1072 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
java-8-oracle 1081 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Still, when I want to change default jre I am getting the below error. What may be the alternate method to start Android Studio either by solving or bypassing this issue. Help appreciated. Thanks!

`ubuntu@ubuntu-Vostro-1450:/usr/lib$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for apt`
`

Comment: `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch getting the same error as above